# Looping over an error to scrape a page in Python

Tags: python, loops

I'd like to run an **'if is error'** *do something* **'else'** *do something else* loop in Python.

This is a general question, but in my particular application, I'm scraping information from a web page; navigating to the next page; and repeating the loop until there are no more pages left to scrape. So the terminating condition is an error telling me there are no more pages left.

For example:

```
no_more_pages = False
while no_more_pages == False:
    if link[-1].find('a')['href'] is False:
         no_more_pages = True 
    else:
        current_link = link[-1].find('a')['href']
```

Obviously the syntax here is wrong. If someone could point me in the right direction, that'd be very helpful.

Comment: The syntax is valid, there is no loop and no error. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @MisterMiagi hopefully my edits have clarified the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I completely get your question but you may try something like a try except block. If there's any errors caused by the conditions of the if statement, you can place the code inside a try block and in case of any error, it will execute the except clause:

```
try:
    if not link[-1].find('a')['href'] is False:
        current_link = link[-1].find('a')['href']
except:
    no_more_pages = True
```

Comment: If you're not completely sure, you shouldn't give an answer. Instead, you should first ask OP questions to clarify what's bothering you. And then answer.

Comment: @specbug this is exactly what I was after. Many thanks and sorry for my confusing question

Comment: @Barton sure just mark the answer correct so others won't think I was just spitballing here!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using beautiful soup. In that case... you can use `.has_attr('href')` if you're trying to check for the href attribute which seems odd... If you just want to check if a link is present just check if the child tag exists on the "link" you have defined.